# Meaning of prefix p,p′-?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I recently stumbled across the substance "p,p′-terphenyldicarboxylic acid" in a scientific journal when recently reading about metal–organic frameworks.

Could someone explain the prefix p,p'- to me?

Comment: Related to this is the $p,p'$ prefix for [DDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane), where we have two para chloro substituents on two different phenyl rings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing that this is the compound you are interested in:
[image: p-Terphenyl-4,4′′-dicarboxylic acid]
Sigma labels this compound as p-Terphenyl-4,4′′-dicarboxylic acid (or 1,4-Bis(4-carboxyphenyl)benzene).

In your case, the p,p' indicates that the 2 carboxylic acids are in the para positions on 2 of the phenyl rings.

Answer (score 6):

As **LDC3** has pointed out, the two *p* stand for *para*. But taking into account that there are three different terphenyls, *p,p'*-terphenyldicarboxylic acid is ambiguous.

[image]

An unambiguous name would denote both the terphenyl core, as well as the positions of the $\ce{COOH}$ substituents on the outer rings, such as in ***p*-terphenyl-4,4'-dicarboxylic acid**.